# Поочередный вызов функций для самых маленьких

Tags: javascript, jquery, settimeout, функции

Проблема в том, что на сайте есть 3 блока DIV в них по очереди должен меняться фон, но как это осуществить я не очень понимаю, пока наработки такие:

```
var event1=$('#event1');
var event2=$('#event2');
var event3=$('#event3');
var timerId = function () {
    var timerId1 = setTimeout(function tick() {
        if (event1.hasClass("event-achieve-img1")){
            event1.toggleClass("imgchanged");
        }else{
            event1.toggleClass("imgchanged");
        }
        timerId1 = setTimeout(tick, 2000);
    }, 2000);
    var timerId2 = setTimeout(function tick() {
        var i=0;
        if (event2.hasClass("event-achieve-img2")){
            event2.toggleClass("imgchanged");
        }else{
            event2.toggleClass("imgchanged");
        }
        timerId2 = setTimeout(tick, 4000);
    }, 4000);

    var timerId3 = setTimeout(function tick() {
        var i=0;
        if (event3.hasClass("event-achieve-img3")) {
            event3.toggleClass("imgchanged");
        } else {
            event3.toggleClass("imgchanged");
        }
        timerId3 = setTimeout(tick, 8000);
    }, 8000);
};
timerId();
```

Задумка в том, что функция по #id ищет класс где указан фон, меняет его на класс с другим фоном, но на данном этапе фон в первом DIV меняется 4е раза пока во втором меняется 2а и т.д. Пробовал использовать `clearTimeout();`, но он останавливает `setTimeout` на глухо.
Код HTML: `<div class="container d-flex flex-column text-center event">
    <p><a name="event"></a></p>
    <h2>МЕРОПРИЯТИЯ</h2>
    <p class="event-up">НАШИ СОТРУДНИКИ ОБЕСПЕЧИЛИ:</p>
    <div class=" d-flex flex-row justify-content-around">
        <div class="d-flex align-items-center justify-content-center event-achieve">
            <a class="event-achieve-img1" id="event1" href=""></a>
            <div class="event-achieve-text">
                <h3>БОЛЕЕ</h3>
                <h3> 70 МАТЧЕЙ</h3>
                <p>В РАМКАХ ЛИГИ ЧЕМПИОНОВ</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="d-flex align-items-center justify-content-center event-achieve">
            <a class="event-achieve-img2" id="event2" href="">
            </a>
            <div class="event-achieve-text">
                <h3>БОЛЕЕ</h3> <h3>150 МАТЧЕЙ</h3>
                <p>В РАМКАХ ЛИГИ ЕВРОПЫ</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="d-flex align-items-center justify-content-center event-achieve">
            <a class="event-achieve-img3" id="event3" href=""></a>
            <div class="event-achieve-text">
                <h3>БОЛЕЕ</h3>
                <h3>300</h3>
                <p>КОНЦЕРТОВ И ШОУ</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <p class="event-down">СЛЕДУЮЩИЙ ШАГ:<span>РАБОТА НА ЧМ 2018</span></p>
</div>`

Comment: То бишь для каждого блока есть несколько `background-image` и у каждого блока должен быть грубо говоря слайдер из этих картинок, правильно?

Comment: У каждого блока свой 'background-image' в CSS, и да, должно быть похоже на слайдер.

Comment: Так может лучше не изобретать велосипед, а воспользоваться именно слайдером? Или нужно исключительно кастомное решение?

Comment: Можешь кинуть что у тебя в `html` свёрстано?

Comment: Можно и слайдером, просто что в голову пришло то и сделал.

Comment: Еще такой вопрос, а как мне сделать , чтоб они не одновременно менялись то, нужно чтоб пока на первом из трех блоков поменялась картинка, на других она оставалась стандартная потом, пока на втором блоке поменялось, на первом и третьем она оставалась стандартная и т.д.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если непринципиально использование слайдера, то можно его заюзать, например я часто использую `owl.carousel` , ссылочка - [Owl](https://owlcarousel2.github.io/OwlCarousel2/)
В случае с этим слайдером - все предельно просто, добавляешь его в папку к своим скриптам и подключаешь, в документации всё есть. Будут вопросы - пиши, помогу.
В твоём случае, каждый твой блок - это слайд( или если хочешь менять background этого слайда - то ещё и отдельный слайдер)

Comment: Большое спасибо, сейчас попробую.

Comment: @ViktorSvinkin Всегда пожалуйста)